# Calling a function in a window.location.reload

Tags: javascript, html

How can I call a function in a `window.location.reload`? 
Example function:

```
function myFunction(){
alert('HOWDY!!!');
}
```

using only javascript

Comment: Why call on reload instead of on beforereload?

Comment: I can also do that... but I don't know how. I'm a noob. @Fals

Comment: What does *"in a `window.location.reload`"* even mean? Do you want to call a function when `window.location.reload` is called?

Comment: yes. that's what I want to do @FelixKling